# Make EF convert properties of a castable-to-string-type to string before sending to the database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Is there a way I can tell EF to convert my MultilingualString properties to string before sending them to the database (and the other way around when fetching from database) ? I want to wrap the behaviour to reuse it.

```
public class MyEntity
{
    //  I want this property to be considered a string by EF (it is castable to string)
    public MultilingualString MyProperty { get; set; }
}

public class MultilingualString
{
    public static implicit operator string(MultilingualString mlString)
    {
        return mlString.ToJson();
    }

    public static explicit operator MultilingualString(string json)
    {
        return new MultilingualString(json);
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: One option is to have your `MyProperty` be `[NotMapped]` and have a backing property of type `string` that is mapped (MyProperty would get/set it's value to the backing property).  I hope this is not the best answer, so will leave it as a comment for now.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing all over the place right now... Don't like it and that's why I'm asking... Thanks anyways :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three thoughts:

One is to to generate your classes from a T4 template that will generate the backing field and the [NotMapped] MultilingualString. Technically you'll be writing less code, and each T4 template could use a method you put in from another assembly to keep from repeating the generation code in each template. I do acknowledge that this idea isn't going to make you feel better, though.

Thought two is to use [PostSharp](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a058d5d3-e654-43f8-a308-c3bdfdd0be4a), attribute up your backing fields and have a PostSharp extension create the multilingual fields, or vice versa. The large downside to this is that static analysis tools are not going to like it much.

Thought three is to make `MultilingualString` a [ComplexType](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/04/01/making-complex-types-useful.aspx) that contains the string field as a public property and also has whatever other methods you have built the class to perform at the moment. It will generate a more messy database column name, if you care about that.

I reckon 3 has the most value.

EDIT:

For option 3 you can control the column names if you need to:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().Property(x => x.MyProperty.StringValue)
  .HasColumnName("i_dba_aprvd_rdbl_col_nm")
```

There's no reason this fluent configuration couldn't be generated using reflection to find all such complex property values if there was a rule by which the column name could be determined, e.g. it was the name of the property of type MultilingualString on the entity.

Comment: Thanks! I would definitely use option 3 already, if it wasn't that I can't modify database column names, for backwards compatibility.

Comment: See my EDIT for a suggestion on how to modify the column names. But even if you didn't modify the column names in this fashion, you could alter the migration it generates to use RenameColumn rather than the DropColumn and CreateColumn pairs it would create for you.

Comment: Yeah... I was hoping I could reuse the Column attribute in my code first model... Maybe a custom attribute ?

Comment: Yes, could do. Use reflection to loop through all your types and, for each type, loop through all the properties of type MultilingualString looking for this attribute and the value inside it (to use later when generating the `HasColumnName` call). Then comes the tricky bit - creating and executing the model building code. You could try using expressions to do it.

Comment: Ok, thanks... was hoping for something les hacky, but I guess it's the only way!